# `setup.py develop` with `install_requires` puts `dist-packages` at top of `sys.path` in virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, setuptools, sys.path

I have a directory `~/foo` and all it has is `setup.py` which contains:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name='foo',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=['mock']
)
```

Now, I create a virtual environment using:

```
cd ~
virtualenv --system-site-packages v1
```

And doing `~/v1/bin/python -c "import sys; print sys.path"`, I get

```
['',
 '/home/garrett',
 '/home/garrett/v1/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/garrett/v1/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/garrett/v1/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/garrett/v1/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/garrett/v1/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/garrett/v1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/garrett/v1/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
```

but, when I do

```
sudo pip install mock
cd ~/foo
~/v1/bin/python setup.py develop
```

then setuptools changes my virtualenv's `sys.path` to have `dist-packages` (where `mock` lives) near the top.  I.e., the first 3 entries of `sys.path` become:

```
['',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/home/garrett/foo',
 ...
```

This seems intentional from looking at [the source](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/src/7f3453a0063e/setuptools/command/easy_install.py#cl-1528) which modifies `easy-install.pth`.

## Question

Is there anyway to disable it messing with the position of `dist-packages` in my `sys.path`?  My `dist-packages` directory has other modules in it which are been given unwanted precedence.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the optimal solution, but one way to prevent setuptools from giving `dist_packages` higher precedence is to add the `--always-copy` flag.

```
~/v1/bin/python setup.py develop --always-copy
```